# Setting Authorization header - Flask app using Python Requests and JWT

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, jwt, authorization

I am just learning to code and this has been driving me crazy. I don't know if I am missing something very simple or have a total misunderstanding about how authentication works (very possibly both), however, i would appreciate someone help.

I have created a login route for my flask app which renders the following and successfully allows a user logging in.

[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxVHl.png)

If a user successfully logs in, i want to set the Authorization header using a token generated using JWT. I am using the request libary to do this and get a 200 response but everytime i check the network tab, i can not see the token in the 'Authorization' Response Header.

The idea is that once this Header has been set, i can protect my apis by ensuring a token is present and also use that information to ensure that APIs only return data for that user i.e. decrypt the token to work out the user.

[Network tab - No Authorization Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFfpv.png)

This is my current code. Where am i going wrong? Does my approach sound correct?

```
@loginsBlueprint.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=request.form['username']).first()
        if user is not None and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, request.form['password']):
            token = jwt.encode(
                {'user': request.form['username'], 'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=15)},
                app.config['SECRET_KEY'])

            url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/login'
            headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
            requests.get(url, headers=headers)

            return render_template('landing_page.html')
        else:
            return make_response('Could not verify', 403,
                                 {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm ="Wrong Password !!"'})
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

login.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask Intro - login page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Please login</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{
          request.form.username }}">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{
          request.form.password }}">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
      {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: I have tried changing to `requests.post` but get a 400:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Mar/2021 21:53:29] "←[31m←[1mPOST /login HTTP/1.1←[0m" 400
```

I thought it might be because i'm using CORS and so added this in:

```
CORS(app, expose_headers='Authorization')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things which are confusing here:

1. In the `login()` method, you make a `requests.get()` call. So it looks like you're calling a new endpoint from your app. Is that how it should work? To be exact, you seem to check the user's credentials, issue a JWT and then call the `/login` endpoint of an app listening on port `5000`, setting the JWT as the bearer token.
2. `Authorization` is a request header. You don't use it in responses to the client. If you want to return the JWT to the client use one of the OAuth flows, either the [Code flow](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-code-flow/) (preferably) or the [Implicit flow](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-implicit-flow/).
3. Once you'll get the token to your client, then you should use it as you said - set in the `Authorization` header as a `Bearer` token. As you're using flask, you can use [this filter](https://github.com/curityio/flask-of-oil) to secure your APIs.